Why does the mass term not violate particle number conservation in a free theory?
The Lagrangian of a free real scalar field theory is
$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi\; \partial^{\mu} \phi \; - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2.  $$
If we decompose $\phi$ in terms of the creation and annihilation operators,
$$ \phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{E_p}} (a_p e^{-ip \cdot x} + a_p^{\dagger}e^{+ip \cdot x}) $$
and plug it in the quadratic mass term in the Lagrangian, we will have terms like $a_p a_p$ and $a_p^{\dagger} a_p^{\dagger}$ that clearly destroy and create two particles respectively and hence should violate particle number conservation.
I understand that the number operator $$N = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} a^{\dagger}_p a_p$$ commutes with the Hamiltonian of the free scalar field theory. But how does the presence of the above terms agree with conservation of $N?$

you have to normal order operator products.

The action, which is the integrated Lagrangian, implies that the product of two field operators is integrated over space and time. The term with two creation or two annihilation operators will have a factor of the exponential function, which, when integrated over space and time, gives a Dirac delta function forcing the momentum and energy to zero.
